# How Can the same ad be used more than one spot on the page with google publisher tag?

Tags: javascript, google-publisher-tag

I am trying to render ads with GPT.  I dont care what ad is rendered I am just trying to prove I can render multiple ads on a page.

in a loop I call this function

```
    function foo(id) {
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    var adSlot1 = googletag.defineSlot('/6355419/Travel/Europe/France/Paris',[300, 250], id);
    console.log(adSlot1);
    adSlot1.addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.enableServices();
  });
     googletag.cmd.push(function() {
     googletag.display(id); });
  };
```

a to try to display the same ad in different spots.

I have 3 blocks where the ad should be right now, The iframes are put in this way but the ad is not displayed.  I have tried to just put 2 ads on the page using this code

```
function foo(id) {
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    console.log(id)
    if (id=='block-gptadblock-2'){
    var adSlot1 = googletag.defineSlot('/6355419/Travel/Europe/France/Paris',[300, 250], id);
    adSlot1.addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.enableServices();
    }else{
        var adSlot2 = googletag.defineSlot('/6355419/Travel/Europe/France/Paris',[300, 250], id);
        adSlot2.addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.enableServices();
    }
  });
     googletag.cmd.push(function() { console.log('rendered id: '+id);
     googletag.display(id); });
  };
```

but the ad is still only displayed in one place.  I dont understand what is happening here.